# Insert Multiple values using vqmod

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have created vqmod

```
$this->db->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `continents` (
`continents_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`continents_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`continents_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8");

$rec = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "continents");
if(count($rec) == 0) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "continents(continents_id,continents_name,status) VALUES(1, 'Asia', 1),(2, 'Africa', 1),(3, 'North America', 1),(4, 'South America', 1),(5, 'Antarctica', 1),(6, 'Europe', 1),(7, 'Australia', 1)");
}
```

Using this code table get created but not fill data in table as my code should.

Comment: Do you get some errors?

Comment: 'm not getting any kind of error

Comment: If you run the code in mysql server directly, is it inserting your rows? (By the way, you do not need to specify the value of continents_id, since you are using auto_increment). Are you sure you did not insert some rows previously?

Comment: yes my insert code works on mysql server directly

Comment: What is count($rec) yielding?

Comment: If you drop the table, is your script re-creating it?

Comment: yes its recreating table if not exist

Comment: Then I do not know what could be the problem. You might want to check the error log of your server.